# Tangent line of a polar curve

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates, tangent-line

I need to find the tangent line where $y=a+x$ (so the tangent line of $45°$) of the following line: $r=\sqrt{\sin(2\cdot\theta)}$

first thing i do i find $x(\theta)$ and $y(\theta)$

$x=\sqrt{\sin(2\cdot\theta)}\cdot \cos(\theta)$ and $y=\sqrt{\sin(2\cdot\theta)}\cdot \sin(\theta)$

now i can determine the first derivative of both

$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\cot(2\theta)\cos(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}-\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}$ and $\frac{dy}{d\theta}=\cot(2\theta)\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}+\cos(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}$

now I can find $\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$

$\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = \frac{\cot(2\theta)\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}+\cos(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}}{\cot(2\theta)\cos(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}-\sin(\theta)\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}} = \frac{\cot(2\theta)\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}{\cot(2\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)}$

and this is where i'm stuck

Comment: You want the gradient of the tangent to be $1$, so set $dy/dx=1$ and solve for $\theta$.

Comment: how do i know that the gradient needs to be 1?

Comment: Because you want to find the tangents $y=x+a$, which have gradient $1$.

Comment: sorry got lost in translation with gradient

Comment: @rbird thank you